# tmux is not reading configuration file tmux.conf in /usr/local/etc

Tags: tmux

[tmux.conf file and path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSXmO.png)

Here is my tmux.conf file and despite several attempts it does not seem to be remapping anything. I also had this in ~/.tmux.conf initially (where it also did not work - /usr/local/etc/tmux.conf did not exist at this time either so it should have been used) and then I moved the contents into the tmux.conf to make it available across all users. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refrain from posting links to the content you need help with - instead, embed it in your question with the correct formatting.

Comment: `~/.tmux.conf` is where tmux will read config options. How have you verified that these options are not set?

Comment: All of the default key bindings which I have attempted to remap are still the same (e.g. C-b prefix instead of the C-a that I set).